# Ubuntu 18.04 does not shutdown or suspend | event loop failed: Connection timed out

Tags: 18.04, suspend, shutdown, amd-graphics, thinkpad

### Shutdown Issue

I get the following error when I try to shut down my laptop:

[image]

So I have to forcefully shut it down with the power button.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3
Laptop: ThinkPad E585
Graphics Card: AMD Raven

(By the way, in the screenshot, the numbers in brackets in both the lines keep changing every time. For example, the second number changes to 375 and 376 as well.)

#### Linked Suspend Issue

In addition, I am not able to suspend my laptop as well. It sort of tries to suspend but after a few seconds lock screen comes up so I have forcefully shut down my laptop. I think this suspend issue is connected with the above shutdown issue since they both appeared around the same time.

#### Background

Originally, I had issue with waking up my laptop after suspension (my laptop screen would go black on wake up). I had tried to resolve it but I couldn't and now recently the above shutdown and suspend issues have appeared. I am not sure if the wake-up issue is linked with shutdown/suspend issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the shutdown and suspend issues were due to a recent kernel update. I reinstalled `Ubuntu` and both the issues were fixed.

But the wake-up issue was still there so I replaced `Ubuntu` with `elementary OS`. It didn't help: the wake-up issue was there as well. To fix wake-up issue, I installed the latest version of the kernel (5.4.6) on `elementary OS` and both the shutdown and suspend issues appeared again. So I had to downgrade the kernel version to remove them.

Now, I have installed kernel 4.19.79 (as instructed [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/20989/20018)) and the [amdgpu-pro drivers provided by AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-lin-19-30-unified). The wake-up issue has occurred once after the last nine suspends which is much better a situation than what it used to be (roughly once after every two suspends).

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading one of my PC's with SSD from 18.04 (kernel 4.15.0-xy) to 18.04.3 (kernel 5.0.0-xy) I had the similar shutdown problem with 18.04.3. Since this problem is not happening in my other PC's with the ''original'' Ubuntu 18.04. (now kernel 4.15.0-72), I made fresh installation of the ''original'' 18.04.0 (instead of 18.04.3) and as a result there is no more shutdown problem in this PC.

Source for Ubuntu 18.04.0 (''original'') is  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.0/